# Search and Replace MySQL: nothing was replaced

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, replace

I'm having a table like this called `v3_product_description`.

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+--+
| product_id | language_id |    name     |                            description                             |   tag    |                          meta_description                          |   meta_keywords    | meta_title |  |
+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+--+
|          1 |           2 | Test        | descrition about product. Altijd op voorraad. further description. | tag      | descrition about product. Altijd op voorraad. further description. | keywords           | title      |  |
|          2 |           1 | test        | Beschrijving over het product                                      | tagsss   | metabeschrijving Altijd op voorraad                                | keywords,and so on | title      |  |
|          3 |           2 | Tessdslfkjq | product description                                                | moretags | metadescription Altijd op voorraad                                 | keywords,bullshit  | titlestuff |  |
+------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+------------+--+
```

As you guys can see the phrase `Altijd op voorraad` is very common in my table (I have over 8000 rows in the real database).

`Altijd op voorraad` translated to German is `Immer auf Lager` and the `language_id` for German is `2`.

I'm trying to search and replace that phrase in my tables so I came up with this query:

```
SELECT product_id, language_id, name, description, tag, meta_title, meta_description, meta_keyword,
       REPLACE(meta_description,'Altijd op voorraad','Immer auf Lager')
FROM v3_product_description
WHERE language_id = 2
```

This query should change every `Altijd op voorraad` in column `meta_description` to `Immer auf Lager`. But once executed it doesn't seem to do so when I view the items in my web-shop.

What am I doing wrong? And how to apply the same search/replace at column `description`? Should I do this with a 2nd query or can those 2 be combined?

Comment: One guess are "special" characters.  In other words, perhaps the vowels have accents.

Comment: As you can see in the examples i've given, there are no special characters in those sentences neither are there special characters in the replace function.

Comment: You are only replacing in the read column data. You need to do UPDATE to change the actual table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the column value, but are using a select query.

The correct way to replace your string in the `meta_description` column would be to

```
UPDATE v3_product_description

SET meta_description= REPLACE (meta_description,'Altijd op voorraad','Immer auf Lager')

WHERE language_id = 2
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks this was the answer! I forgot to actually update the values.. wow blue tuesday instead of a blue monday. I really feel stupid now

Comment: @Baklap4 happens to the best of us. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. Cheers

Comment: Will do when i'm able to mark it solved!